# Convex set included in its asymptotic cone

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $S$ be a closed unbounded convex set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and assume that the asymptotic cone $S_{\infty}$ of $S$ has no empty interior. (It is not a line or a half line) Of course I know that I can find $z \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $z+S_{\infty} \subset S.$ I would ask if the converse is also true. Does there exist some $z\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $S \subset z + S_{\infty} ?$

On a picture it is obviously false if the asymptotic cone has empty interior, but if not it seems pretty intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Try $S = \{(x,y): x \ge 0, -x - \sqrt{x} \le y \le x + \sqrt{x}\}$, for which the asymptotic cone is $\{(x,y): |y| \le x\}$.

Comment: Thank you for this counter-example, Do we know exactly what are the convex which can be included in a translation of their asymptotic cone ? (For example it works for a convex with a hyperbolic boundary, etc ...) Are these convex the "asymptotically linear" one ?